# rsync not copying according to --include flag

Tags: rsync

I have dir:

```
- /tmp/test1/
-- 1.txt
-- 2.cert
```

I have another empty dir named /tmp/test2

```
sudo rsync -av --relative --include="*.txt" --exclude="*" --delete-before --chmod=D2775,F664 /tmp/test1/ /tmp/test2/
```

I would've expected 1.txt to be copied, but nothing is copied, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory `/tmp/test1/` gets excluded by the `--exclude="*"` flag and thus `1.txt` is not checked at all.

You need to add `--include="*/"` as first include/exclude flag.
You may also want to add `-m` (or `--prune-empty-dirs`) to avoid creating empty directories.

```
sudo rsync -amv --relative --include="*/" --include="*.txt" --exclude="*" --delete-before --chmod=D2775,F664 /tmp/test1/ /tmp/test2/
```

Comment: Thank you! But I don't understand, isn't the   `--include="*/"` overrules `--exclude="*"` thus it should've copied all the files?

Comment: No, `--include="*/"` only matches directories (note the trailing slash).